# Problem of Java String intern method when using StringBuilder with append method creating a String

Tags: java, string

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = new StringBuilder("Jav").toString();
        a.intern();
        String c = "Jav";
        System.out.println(a == c);  //false
    }
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = new StringBuilder("Ja").append("v").toString();
        a.intern();
        String c = "Jav";
        System.out.println(a == c);  //true
    }
```

[image]

I do not understand why first one would print out false, but the second one print out true. I think those should print out true because after calling the intern method, the reference of a would be written into the string pool and c will point to the reference of a. Can someone explain the difference? Thanks!

My JDK Version: OpenJDK 17.0.7

Btw I also get the same result when using StringBuffer.

Comment: Do check this again! I have `false` in both case for `11` and `17` Java.

Comment: I've checked and I still have true in the second case, I'm so confused.

Comment: Yep. This is really wired to me! I can't explain this.

Comment: @OlegCherednik Are you perhaps executing both snippets in the same run? I had 2 `false` results if I execute them together (as 2 separate methods called from main), but if I execute them independently, the second snippet prints `true`.

Comment: It's order of execution. In the first example, you have the string literal `"Jav"` _before_ the call to `a.intern()`, meaning there was already a `"Jav"` in the string pool. In the second example, the first time the string literal `"Jav"` appears is _after_ the call to `a.intern()`, meaning that call actually puts the object referenced by `a` in the pool. Then later, doing `c = "Jav"` gives you that object back (thus `a == c`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### TL;DR and solution

The important difference is the location of the first `"Jav"` literal/interning.

`intern()` *returns* you the canonical reference. If a canonical reference already exists, it is not updated.

Hence, you need to change `a.intern();` to `a = a.intern();`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = new StringBuilder("Jav").toString();
    a = a.intern();
    String c = "Jav";
    System.out.println(a == c); //this is true now
}
```

#### Why and how the examples are different

In your second example, `==` returns `true` because the `String` returned by `StringBuilder` is made the canonical reference in the first `intern()` call and the `String` literal is resolved lazily and gives.

The literal then gives you the canonical reference which is the same object you already have.

In the first example, a canonical `String` already exists with that content hence the `intern()` method just returns the *existing* canonical `String` as opposed to making the current `String` canonical.

#### Further comments

For a more detailed analysis of your code, see @[Nidheesh R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22588349/nidheesh-r)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77242797/10871900).

As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77242671/problem-of-java-string-intern-method-when-using-stringbuilder-with-append-method/77242762?noredirect=1#comment136174570_77242762) by @[Jorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8681/jorn), you shouldn't need `String#intern` anyways and you should also not use `==` on `String`s.

Also, depending on that behaviour is fragile. If you are using tools like GraalVM's `native-image`, using a different JVM or maybe some of [Project Leyden](https://openjdk.org/projects/leyden)'s condensers, things like this might work a bit differently.

Comment: then how it works in second case?

Comment: I still don't know why the second one(StringBuilder using append method) doesn't need to change a = a.intern();but can print out true.

Comment: As I explained, the second one first _makes_ the `StringBuilder` created `String` canonical which works because there is no canonical `String` with that content before.

Comment: You should note that there is basically no reason to muck around with `String.intern` at all. Just let the JVM handle it, it'll be fine.

Answer (score 4):

As @dan1st mentioned, this is due to the way the `intern()` method works in Java.

#### first `main` method

1. You are creating a new `String` object `a` using a `StringBuilder` and then call `toString()` on it. This creates a new `String` object with the value "Jav."
2. Then, you are calling `a.intern()`, which attempts to add the string "Jav" to the string pool. But there is already a string "Jav" in the string pool (because of `new StringBuilder("jav");`). So, the `intern()`-call does nothing and `a` still refers to the newly created `String` object.
3. Finally, when you compare `a` and `c` using `a == c`, it checks if they both are referring to the same object. In this case, they do not because `a` refers to the newly created `String` object, and `c` refers to the "Jav" string in the string pool. Hence, the result is false.

#### second `main` method

1. You are creating a new String object `a` using a `StringBuilder` by appending "Ja" and "v" together. This creates a new `String` object with the value "Jav".
2. Then, you are calling `a.intern()`, which attempts to add the string "Jav" to the string pool. But, as the string "Jav" is not in the string pool, it adds it, and the reference to the string in the string pool is returned.
3. And now, when you compare `a` and `c` using `a == c`, they are referring to the same string object in the string pool (the one created by `a.intern()`), which returns the result as true.

Comment: Both methods have String c = "Jav"; Why are the string pools different? (first one "Jav" is in the pool, the second one "Jav" is not in the pool.)

Comment: the only change in the code is append() method then why its working differently?

Comment: It might help to note that in the first example the fragment `new StringBuilder("Jav")` requires a reference to the string "Jav" and already puts it into the string pool whereas in the second fragment `new StringBuilder("Ja").append("v")` the two strings "Ja" and "v" are added to the string pool.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - but is easily fixed. 'first main' point 1 says: "Because of the `String c = "jav";`" - that's the wrong part. it's because of the `new StringBuilder("jav")` - that makes "jav" and as its from a string literal in a class file, is interned then and there, hence there's now `"jav"` in the pool, but `a` is not that (because stringbuilder doesn't look in the pool; most things don't). `a.intern()` then does not change the pool but returns the reference - the rest of this answer is then correct.

Comment: You're right! I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally good practice to use the String.equals() method when comparing strings, not == .

When I use `System.out.println(a.equals(c));` in your first example, the result is true.

See the [api spec here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()).

Comment: Although this is true, it doesn't answer the question: *"Can someone explain the difference?"* Nothing in the question indicates that the poster does not know about strings and `equals`. They want to understand the behaviour of `intern` and `==` anyway.

Comment: OK Thanks, @Lii. I will pay attention to the exact question from now on.